# Selenium locate custom html attribute

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

```
<div>
<input id="" class="form" type="text" z:validate="" z:prompt="form1.prompt('submit')" z:placeholder="" z:tie="submit" z:disabled="{form1.isEnabled('sumbitApply')}" placeholder="" maxlength="20">
</div>
```

I want to locate the element using z:tie="submit" custom attribute.

So far I have tried below options. But that did not work.

```
//input[@z:tie='sumbit']
//input[z:tie='sumbit']
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're having trouble because of the ":" in your attributes.

if you change the ":" to "_" everything will work fine.